# index match in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I have the following dataframe

| value | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 7.0 | 8.0 |
| 2.0 | 9.0 | 8.8 |
| 3.0 | 9.5 | 9.1 |
| 4.0 | 10.0 | 9.4 |
| 5.0 | 13.0 | 9.7 |
| 6.0 | 15.0 | 9.9 |
| 7.0 | 16.0 | 10.6 |
| 8.0 | 17.0 | 17.0 |

What I'm attempting to do:

example:

I'm thinking some sort of if/else statetement:

```
    -if 
        A < B
      return 1.0 ==> since A=7.0 < B=8.0
    if A=B,
      return value => if A=17, B=17 return 8.0
    -else: 
        if A > B
         look at the two smaller values closest to match A from B column and return value from B+1.
         Let's say the value A=9.0 so in this example it's going to check B = 8.0 and B=8.8 and return the value for B=9.1 which is 3.0.
```

Couple more examples in case it's unclear:

if A=9, check B=8.0 and B=8.8 and return 3.0

if A=9.5, check B=9.1 and B=9.4 and return 5.0

if A=10.0, check B=9.7 and B=9.9 and return 7.0

if A=16, check B=9.9 and B=10.6 and return 8.0

I tried using numpy for this, and indexing it... np.where looked promising but I keep getting stuck in the second part. Can anyone help? It's safe to assume that the values are sorted in the ascending order.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide your desired output for this specific example. In general, when asking questions on SO, make it as simple as possible for the community to understand your problem and to replicate it.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I stated the desired output. The expected output is the return float number from the corresponding value column. 
if A = 7.0. A < smallest B=8.0 so expected output is 1.0
if A = 9.0. A > B, so expected output is 3.0. I'm happy to provide more examples if that's still not clear.

Comment: do you expect this output list: `[1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]`?

Comment: No, just one digit if B>A, so 1, and 3 if A>B in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say it, but your question is not clear at all. You made strange mistakes and did not explain clearly what you wanted.

So, what this program does:

1. If A < B, return "value" from the same line;
2. If A > B, looks through the whole dataframe from the current B up to the end and takes "value" from the first line where B is more than A.

If it is not what you wanted, please, give more clear explanation) Delighted to help you.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
               "value": [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6], 
               'A': [7., 9., 9.5, 10., 13., 15.],
               'B': [8., 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, 8.4, 8.5]
             })
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['A'][i] < df['B'][i]: 
        print(df["value"][i])
    else:
        for j in range(i, df.shape[0]):
            if df['A'][i] < df['B'][j]:
                print(df["value"][j])
```

Edited: output is 1.0, 3.0, 4.0.
I've just seen that you noticed your signs, sorry)

The second code (looks for the closest number from the whole dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
               "value": [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6], 
               'A': [7., 9., 9.5, 10., 13., 15.],
               'B': [8., 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, 8.4, 8.5]
             })
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['A'][i] < df['B'][i]: print(df["value"][i])
    else:
        b_column = df['B']
        b_column_residuals = abs(df['B'] - df['A'][i])
        print(df["value"][b_column_residuals.idxmin()])
```

The trird code (looks for the closest number from the current B and one below (or above when the last B)):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
               "value": [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6], 
               'A': [7., 9., 9.5, 10., 13., 15.],
               'B': [8., 8.8, 9.1, 9.4, 8.4, 8.5]
             })
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['A'][i] < df['B'][i]: print(df["value"][i])
    else:
        try:
            if abs(df['B'][i] - df['A'][i]) < abs(df['B'][i + 1] - df['A'][i]): print(df["value"][i])
            else: print(df["value"][i + 1])
        except:
            if abs(df['B'][i] - df['A'][i]) < abs(df['B'][i - 1] - df['A'][i]): print(df["value"][i])
            else: print(df["value"][i - 1])
```

The fourth code (compares the current B, the B above and below):

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['A'][i] < df['B'][i]: print(df["value"][i])
    else:
        if i == 0: # When the first row.
            if abs(df['B'][i] - df['A'][i]) < abs(df['B'][i + 1] - df['A'][i]): print(df["value"][i])
            else: print(df["value"][i + 1])
        elif i == df.shape[0] - 1: # When the last row.
            if abs(df['B'][i] - df['A'][i]) < abs(df['B'][i - 1] - df['A'][i]): print(df["value"][i])
            else: print(df["value"][i - 1])
        else: # When in the middle.
            AB_i = abs(df['B'][i] - df['A'][i])
            AB_iabove = abs(df['B'][i + 1] - df['A'][i])
            AB_ibelow = abs(df['B'][i - 1] - df['A'][i])
            if AB_i == min(AB_i, AB_iabove, AB_ibelow): # if the current B is the closest.
                print(df["value"][i]) 
            elif AB_iabove == min(AB_i, AB_iabove, AB_ibelow): # if B above the current is the closest.
                print(df["value"][i - 1])
            else: # if B below the current is the closest.
                print(df["value"][i + 1])
```

It CAN'T return you only 1.0 and 3.0: if it does, it is illogical based on your current description of the program.

The fifth code (checks all the values forward and prints "value" to the first B > A. If there is none B > A, prints nothing.)

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['A'][i] < df['B'][i]: print(df["value"][i])
    else:
        for j in range(i, df.shape[0]): # from i so that it won't raise an error.
            if df['A'][i] < df['B'][j]: print(df["value"][j]); break
```

The sixth code (checks B and B above, prints "value" from the string below closer B) (sorry for unformatted first time code):

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['A'][i] < df['B'][i]: print(df["value"][i])
    else:
        try: # it is not needed with current data, it is made for other data.
            if df['B'][i] - df['A'][i] <= df['B'][i - 1] - df['A'][i]: print(df["value"][i])
            else: print(df["value"][i + 1])
        except: print(df["value"][i])
```

I asked you about the first line for this code may be used not only for the given data - data can be different, but the program must work anyway. In this case the program checks B in front of A and B above, returns "value" below the closer B. If it is impossible to compare current B with one above (it can only happen in the first line if A isn't < B), returns "value" from the same line (i.e. from the first).
*Gosh, I hope that's what you need.*

The seventh code (does the same as the previous one but only for inputed A):

```
try:
    A = float(input())
    i = df[df['A'] == A].index.values.astype(int)[0]
    if df['A'][i] < df['B'][i]: print(df["value"][i])
    else:
        try: # it is not needed with current data, it is made for other data.
            if df['B'][i] - df['A'][i] <= df['B'][i - 1] - df['A'][i]: print(df["value"][i])
            else: print(df["value"][i + 1])
        except: print(df["value"][i])
except: print("No such value for A in dataframe.")
```

The eighth code (replaces all the values in A column with inputed A and searches for "value" for the closest B in the B column):

```
A = float(input())
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df['A'][i] = A
residuals = abs(df['A'] - df['B'])
i = residuals.idxmin()
print(df["value"][i])
```

Comment: Can you make one more adjustment and I can take it from there? In the else statement, if A=9.0, check B=8.0 and B=8.8 and return value for B=9.1 which is 3.0. 
more examples:
if A=10, check B=9.7 and B=9.9 and return 7.0 which corresponds to B=10.6.

Comment: I edited the description. Hopefully that will clear the requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, can you rephase it?

Comment: 1) Did I understand you correctly: we compare current B and B above current (for example, B= 8.8 & B=8.0 for A=9.0) and return "value" from the line under the closest B (in the current example it is 3.0 since B=8.8 is closer to A=9.0 and we take "value" from the line below - where B=9.1 and "value" = 3.0)?

Comment: 1) that's right!
2) if A=7.0, A<B so we just return whatever value we're currently are on which is 1.0, no need to check for other Bs

Comment: Check now. The sixth.

Comment: the print statements are still messed up. I think it we can predefine A that may help? So instead reading the values of A in the data, you can just pass it as a parameter?

Comment: before submitting another code, can you check print statement? It should only return one value for given A

Comment: You need to get "value" for given A, not from Dataframe? How then connect the dataframe and given A?

Comment: the values for A would be from dataframe, so if I look at the A column, I can pass 9 which is within the dataframe and I should get 3.0 as an output

Comment: You haven't answered to my comment yet so I just published the new code.

Comment: your float A doesn't do anything. I think you need to replace it with all the references to df["A"]

Comment: Wait, you mean that you just need to find the "value" for the closest B for the given A? Why is there need to use pandas then? And why do you need to replace all A values with the given A? Why did you write A values in the table then?

Comment: A column is mostly for the users so they will know what values to pick

Comment: I can't choose the data, I'm working with pandas dataframe

Comment: Check it now...

Comment: you got it!! thanks a lot, that's perfect :)